# pandas groupby apply почему иногда работает построчно, а иногда по столбцам?

Tags: python, pandas

Столько лет работаю в python и вот беда.

У меня есть большая таблица где есть, допустим, всего три столбца: дата, товар, и его цена `['Date','Product','Price']`.

Мне нужно сгруппировать по товарам, применить кастомную функцию (пускай для простоты будет shift) в порядке дат и заджойнить новый столбец к имеющимся столбцам по товару и дате.

У меня сразу стоит мультииндекс, поэтому вот что я делаю:
`df.join(df.reset_index().set_index('Date').groupby('Product').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.Price.shift(-1), name='shifted_price')))`

По началу все работало. Но потом данных стало больше и я начал ловить ошибку, мол нет столбца с именем 'Date'. Полазил в коде и увидел, что `df.reset_index().set_index('Date').groupby('Product').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.Price.shift(-1), name='shifted_price'))` больше не выглядит как Series с мультииндексом `['Product','Date']`, теперь это DataFrame с индексами 'Product' и столбцами 'Date'. Я не растерялся сплавил ее в Series, задал нужный мультииндекс и заджойнил как и раньше.

Так я жил еще какое-то время. Но данных стало еще больше и та же конструкция из DataFrame снова превратилась в Series с мультииндексом. Причем формат изначальной таблицы не меняется, dtypes те же (даже диапазоны значений примерно те же). Но вот формат, как pandas возвращает комбинацию `groupby(...).apply(...)` почему-то поменялся.

Я уже облазил кучу документации по pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply, но там ничего не сказано про возвращаемый формат. Я залез внутрь исходников, все должно работать идеально. Кто-нибудь, пожалуйста, объясните мне, где происходит магия? Я чувствую себя полным идиотом в python.

Мне не трудно переключать коды, к тому же я теперь обрабатываю через try-except по методу "какой из способов сработает, пускай так и посчитается", но это явный костыль. Хочется понимать, что происходит. Так недалеко разочароваться в питонистских методах и вернуться к циклам, пускай долго, но зато без сюрпризов. Хотя хочется верить, что проблема на поверхности, просто у меня случился затык в голове.

Comment: Мне вот вообще непонятно, зачем вы делаете столько сложных телодвижений с созданием нового столбца через reset index-set index и join. обычный метод `transform` вас не спасет? Кроме того, groupby всегда по умолчанию группирует построчно, если вы явно не задали `axis`. Скорее всего, у вас что-то не то с мультииндексом.

Comment: Так, применение функции должно происходит внутри групп. Если я сделаю трансформ, то shift сдвинет первую цену продукта А в последнюю цену продукта В. Здесь shift приведен для примера, расчетные функции NPV гораздо сложнее. Поэтому если вы не понимаете зачем нужен apply в связке с groupby, то уж извиняйте. Groupby группирует построчно - все верно, apply для структуры GroupBy возвращает новый столбец - так должно быть по умолчанию. Но вот этот новый столбец в ходе процесса порой транспонируется и вместо того чтобы получить серию с мультииндексом, я получаю как бы pivot таблицу.

Comment: А вот почему я не группирую по уровням мультииндекса - потому что криворук - не знаю, как поизящнее это записать,группировка по индексу дублирует группируемый индес и получается мультииндекс ['Product','Product','Date'] - мне показалось проще сбросить индекс и объявить его явно, но тут, возможно, есть более изящное решение - просто повторюсь, не знаю какое.

Comment: Метод `transform` работает внутри группы. между группами значения шифтится не будут, если вы об этом.

Comment: Да, извиняюсь, посмотрел, применяет функцию по всем столбцам, при этом, по сути изменяя столбцы. Т.к. мне нужно сохранить и старый столбцец тоже и не ко всем столбцам нужно применять функцию, думаю ближе все-таки apply. Но в корне проблема не в выборе метода для применения функции, а в том что группировка+применение функции работают немного по разному по мере добавления данных в таблицу. Как связаны телодвижения reset index-set index-join с "проще использовать transform" я к сожалению тоже не осознал. выбор apply связан с тем, что он позволяет использовать в формулах несколько столбцов

Comment: df["новый столбец"] = df.groupby("по какому столбцу группировать")["какой столбец группировать"].transform("shift") - это в разы проще и короче вашей конструкции. Никакие другие столбцы не изменяются, в том-то и суть. И тут так же можно использовать несколько столбцов. Почитайте уже документацию с примерами. думаю, я более не буду комментировать этот вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.